# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 When using Linux

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have looked through all of these, but my solution is not there.
[image]

I am adding linux support to my game. It works fine on windows (32 and 64 bit, windows 7 and 8 tested), however when I gave it to a tester on linux he is getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  /home/jai/Downloads/res/linux/liblwjgl.so: /home/jai/Downloads/res/linux/liblwjgl.so: wrong ELF class:  ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at StartScreenExperiments.Test2$1.run(Test2.java:107)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

The code I use to change operating systems is the following:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
        // Windows
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("res/natives-win").getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) {
        // Mac OS X
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("res/macosx").getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux")) {
        // Linux
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("res/linux").getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Sun")) {
        // SunOS (Solaris)
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("res/solaris").getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        notsupported = true;
    }
```

And I have the following natives in res/linux:
[image]

Reading other posts, I know it is something to do with 32 bit on 64 bit or 64 bit on 32 bit or whatever, but I do not actually know how to fix it.

Obviously I would like my game to work on all the above listed OS's, no matter if they are 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Can you find out the user's 1. kernel architecture (`uname -m`), 2. java architecture (`java -version`), and 3. any unmet linker dependencies for liblwjgl*.so (`ldd native/linux/liblwjgl*.so`)?

Comment: @thatotherguy So now I have to wait for a guy in australia to get back from school which will be over 15 hours.... Gah (expect the info in ~15 hours). Would you recommend I add a bounty to this question by the way, since it has got little attention?

Comment: I would have tried to reproduce the problem in a vm.